# grep and awk commands not returning or storing output to the variable

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, text-processing, grep

I have a (`users.csv`) file containing a list of id's of all employees. I need is to loop through this file for each employee, search if it exists in `backup.txt` file using `grep` and store the output in a variable (`user_data`) for printing.

I tried `echo` the value of `user_data`, but its printing as empty, wich reason why is `user_data` returning empty? Although `user_id` does contain the id of an employee, I believe it is not working because of this loop.

My script:

```
#!/bin/bash

header=true

while IFS=',' read -r user_id; do

if $header; then
        header=false
        continue
    fi

  user_data=$(grep "uid=$user_id" disable_Backup.txt)
  echo "User is $user_id"
  echo "Data is $user_data"

done < users.csv
```

Contents of `users.csv`:

```
user_id
x220988
x240755
x260698
```

Contents of `disable_Backup.txt`:

```
uid=x220988
inetUserStatus=Active
EmployeeStatus=ACT

uid=x240755
inetUserStatus=Active
EmployeeStatus=ACT

uid=x260698
inetUserStatus=Active
EmployeeStatus=ACT
```

What do I need to do to store the output from `grep` into `user_data` variable?

Comment: Does your users.csv file have Windows line endings (CRLF)? Check with command `file users.csv`

Comment: btln000266:infra$ file users.csv
users.csv: ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators

Comment: So you are trying to match `uid=x220988<CR>` against `uid=x220988` and it's not matching

Comment: yes, its matching if I run the same grep outside this file but inside the loop it seem the grep is returning empty, nothing is being printed when I echo user_data

Comment: So when you run the same grep outside this file, how are you assigning value(s) to `user_id`? by `read`ing them from the users.csv file?

Comment: running it in a separate shell script file by hard-coding the value of user_id
```
#!/bin/sh

user_id="x220988"
user_data=$(grep "uid=$user_id" disable_Backup.txt)
echo "The value of uid for user $user_id is $user_data"
```
Below is the output of above which I want in my orignal script.

./test.sh
The value of uid for user x220988 is uid=x220988

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `users.csv` file has Windows-style line terminators (CRLF), whereas your `disable_Backup.txt` file apparently has Unix-style (LF).

When you `IFS=',' read -r user_id` from `users.csv`, the `user_id` variable will contain the trailing CR character - so when you try to match it against lines from `disable_Backup.txt` - which has no such characters - the match fails.

Either make sure both files have the same line endings (the easiest way is using `dos2unix` or `unix2dos`), or strip off the carriage return character before you pass the value to `grep`:

```
user_data=$(grep "uid=${user_id%$'\r'}" disable_Backup.txt)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that worked :)

Comment: @HaiderAliSyed Please see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers)